# Parallel BFS OpenMP C

Tags: c, graph, parallel-processing, openmp, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to develop the code to make a parallel version of the BFS (topDown) algorithm on a graph. This is the code I have developed so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>
#define MAX 10000
      
int n; 
int v;
long dim = (long) MAX*MAX;
long* adj;
void create_graph();
void BF_Traversal();
void BFS(int v);
 

int main()
{
create_graph();
BFS(v);
return 0;
}


bool isEmpty(int* array){
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (array[i] != -1)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
void topDownStep(int* frontier, int* next, int* parents){
  int index = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) 
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (frontier[i]!=-1){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            long offset= frontier[i]*MAX + j;
            if (adj[offset]==1 && j!=v){
                if (parents[j] ==-1){
                    parents[j]=frontier[i];
                    next[index] = j;
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

  }

}
void BFS(int startVertex){
    int* frontier = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int* next = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int* parents = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    memset( frontier, -1, n*sizeof(int) );
    memset( next, -1, n*sizeof(int) );
    memset( parents, -1, n*sizeof(int) );
    frontier[0] = startVertex;

    while (!isEmpty(frontier))
    {
    
      topDownStep(frontier,next,parents);
      printf("Visited frontier:\n");
      for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(frontier[i]!=-1)
            printf("%d\t",frontier[i]);
          
      }
      printf("\n");
      memcpy(frontier,next,n*sizeof(int));
      memset( next, -1, n*sizeof(int) );
    }
}

void create_graph(){
adj = malloc(dim* sizeof(long));
int count,max_edge,origin,destin;
srand(time(NULL));
// FILE *in_file  = fopen("graph.txt", "r");
// fscanf(in_file, "%d %d", &n , &v);
// printf("%d - %d",n,v);
// max_edge = n*(n-1);
// while ( fscanf(in_file, "%d %d", &origin,&destin) != EOF )  { 
//     if((origin == -1) && (destin == -1))
//         break;
    
//     if(origin>=n || destin>=n || origin<0 || destin<0)
//         printf("Invalid edge!\n");
//     else
//         adj[origin][destin] = 1;
//         adj[destin][origin] = 1;
//     } 
n = MAX;
v= 0;
max_edge = n*(n-1);
for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        int val = rand()%MAX;
        if(i!=val){
            long offset = i*MAX+val;
            adj[offset]=1;
    }
    }
}
}
```

I'm not sure if this approach is good or not for parallelizing such algorithm (see topDownStep).

The code seems to work correctly as the frontiers are visited in the right order, but I have a feeling that the code is not optimized.

Also I am afraid that race conditions may occur even if from the tests I have done it seems that this does not happen.

I look forward to your advice and I always thank you for your availability.

Comment: Please precise a specific question. If the problem is not precisely identified and you just want a review of your code, then please post your code on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. That being said, your code has race conditions: `index` is shared and `index++` is not protected. I think this also applies to `parents`. Did you check the results are correct (when run multiple times)?

Comment: Besides the race conditions @Jerome mentioned, you have a bigger problem: the result may depend on the order of execution of `i` loop. Run the loop in reverse order and check if you obtain the same result.

Comment: If frontiers have to be "visited in the right order" and n=10000 only, the serial code will be faster as OpenMP overheads are bigger than the actual work.

Comment: Code too complicated for me. Can you tell what youi're trying to do? Search for what? And you have a fully general undirected graph? At least I hope it's simply connected......